# Recursive unzipping with 7zip in Windows

Tags: for-loop, cmd, 7zip

I've got password-protected 7zip files in folders like

```
-Data
-->Bob
--->Bob1.7z
--->Bob2.7z
--Anne
--->Anne1.7z
--->Anne2.7z
```

I'd like to recurse through all of the folders and unzip all archives, into a folder named after the archive at the same level. I've got:

```
FOR /f "usebackq" %a in ('DIR /s /b *.7z') do 7z.exe e -p wibble "%a"
```

but when I run it I get

> ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified. DIR

So it seems as if it's looking for the literal string 'DIR' rather than getting the directory listing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try using actual "backquotes" (hence the name of the `/f` option) instead of single quotes: `FOR /f "usebackq" %a in (\`DIR /s /b *.7z\`) do 7z.exe e -p wibble "%a"`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

And for those who come after me, the full command I ended up using is:

```
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %a in (`DIR /s /b *.7z`) do 7z.exe e "%a" -pwibble
```

('delims=' allows spaces in filenames, and the password is put in the right place)